# PHP SimpleXML DOM using between functions

Tags: php, dom, function, simplexml

I have been trying to get my head around how simplexml and dom updates XML between functions. The reason i ask is that the code i have written seems to work, but without me having to declare anything as global, and im a little confused as to why it does this.

For example, i have this (simplified) code:

```
<?

foreach ($filenames as $filename) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($filename);
    updateXml($xml);
    $xml->last_update = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $xml->asXML($filename);
}

function updateXml($xml) {
    //...
    if ($data = $xml->xpath('//data/info[product_id="' . $product_data['id'] . '"]')) {
        $parent = $data[0]->xpath("parent::*");
        $data = updateItem($parent[0], $product_data);
    } else {
        $product = addItem($xml->products, $product_data['id']);
        $data = updateItem($product, $product_data);
    }
}

function updateItem($parent, $product_data) {

    $node = dom_import_simplexml($parent);
    $dom = $node->ownerDocument;

    $product = $dom->createElement('product');
    $node->appendChild($product);
    $item = $dom->createElement('id', $product_data['id']);
    $product->appendChild($item);
    $item = $dom->createElement('name', $product_data['name']);
    $product->appendChild($item);
    $item = $dom->createElement('url');
    $product->appendChild($item);
    $cdata = $dom->createCDATASection($product_data['url']);
    $item->appendChild($cdata);
    $item = $dom->createElement('price', $product_data['price']);
    $product->appendChild($item);

    return $node;
}

?>
```

Can you please help me understand how the XML is being updated between the functions without needing to declare it as global? I know it seems strange to ask about something that works, but i need to get my head around it :-)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a copy of the instance of an object through each of your functions.

You can think of parameter passing as *sharing* the same instance of an object to each of your functions, opposed to declaring it `global`.

Comment: Ok interesting, thanks for the reply. So if i update just one part of the xml, it will apply to the whole object? Also, do i need to retun $node in the final function, is it required?

Comment: If you update one part of the xml inside the `$filename` it would apply to the object. Depending on how your code will be used depends on when to return variables. If you want to do something with that `$node`, such as `echo` the `$node` in `updateItem`, it will `echo` because it is returned.

Comment: Ok great! So if i just want to use updateItem to modify the xml, the save using asXML, i dont need to return anything from the function?

Comment: Look at this line, `$data = updateItem($product, $product_data);`, you are setting `$data` to be the value returned from calling `updateItem` so you would need to return `$node` in this situation.

Comment: Ok i understand much better now, thanks for your help, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You think you're only passing the nodes that you stored in $product (or other var): you're not.  You're passing the original object, with some parameters set about a selected nodeset.

Comment: Ahhh ok, so as long as i pass something back which relates to a part of $xml, i will be ok?